# Angular DatePipe incorrect format in server

Tags: angular, date-pipe

I'm trying to format my date value to `M/d/yy` using the Angular datepipe. It works in localhost wery well but when to deploy on remote server - the datepipe sets an  incorrect format - `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM`.

There my code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date',
  template:
    '<span>{{ curDate | date: this.dateFormat }}</span>',
})
export class DateComponent<M> extends BaseComponent<M> {
  dateFormat = 'M/d/yy';
  curDate = this.date // 2021-03-24T07:57:50.711Z

}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: There's no issue in your code. If you can add more detail regarding your error/ code then we can look into what's the issue for not working.

Comment: I don't think you should have to use `this` in your template, It can just be 
`{{ curDate | date: dateFormat }}`